# Try to open text file from dataframe but get index out of range error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to open a text file saved from a dataframe in a python program but get `list index out of range error`. The program works fine with other text files but not this one. What is wrong?

This reads a csv file into the dataframe program:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'CS OBIEE reportR1 02-01-2021.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['Bill Account Number','Tariff Rate Type', 'Project Id',
                                  'Project Name', 'CS Project Capacity', 'KW Allocation'])
```

At the end of the program I save the output to a txt file:

```
no_duplicate_accountsDF.to_csv('no_duplicate_accounts.txt', header = False, '
                               'index = False, sep = '\t')
```

Then I try to open this txt file in another python program:

```
filename = 'no_duplicate_accounts.txt'
fhand = open(filename)
```

But I get this error:

```
File "C:\marks_python_folder\Homework\OBIEE CS reports\DataFrame tests\FEJA_Final__obiee_report_061121_R1_081821.py", line 93, in <module>
account_no = words[0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: The error is on a line you don't show. What is `words`?

Comment: You also have a `no_duplicate_accountsDF` that could easily be empty.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the file "C:\marks_python_folder\Homework\OBIEE CS reports\DataFrame tests\FEJA_Final__obiee_report_061121_R1_081821.py"

then go to line 93 and check why the list "words" is empty. Since you are not providing a code snippet of this file it is not really possible to help you further.

I can imagine that some loop is collecting words and the script doesn't handle the case what should happen when the list remains empty. As this case is not handled you are getting this error.

Comment: Here is the beginning and end of the program that creates the txt file I want to open in another program later:

Comment: data = pd.read_csv(r'CS OBIEE reportR1 02-01-2021.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['Bill Account Number','Tariff Rate Type', 'Project Id', 'Project Name', 'CS Project Capacity', 'KW Allocation'])
THEN I CREATE THE LIST OF ACCOUNTS: no_duplicate_accountsDF = df.drop_duplicates(['Bill Account Number', 'Project Id'], keep = 'last') THEN I SAVE IT TO A TEXT FILE: 
no_duplicate_accountsDF.to_csv('no_duplicate_accounts.txt', header = False, index = False, sep = '\t')

Comment: This is the main program that takes the text file and processes it. I open the text file: import pandas as pd
import numpy
               

filename = 'no_duplicate_accounts.txt'
fhand = open(filename) Then I create the variable names from each line: for line in fhand:
    
     words = line.split()
     account_no = words[0]
   It fails at account_no = words[0]: File "C:\marks_python_folder\Homework\OBIEE CS reports\DataFrame tests\Stackoverflow_questionrt_081821.py", line 93, in <module>
    account_no = words[0] IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Thanks for feedback. words is the line.split: for line in fhand:
    
    length_of_line = len(line) words = line.split()
    
    no_words = len(words)

Comment: account_no = words[0]. This works fine when I open a text file that I created from an excel file. But it doesn't work on a txt file created from the dataframe. Does DF organize data differently? The format of the two kinds of text files look normal. Let me know what the best format is for submitting questions and comments. I'm new to this.

Comment: Meant to mention I don't think the no_duplicate_accountsDF is empty because I save it to a text file. When I look at the text file it has all the data in it. Let me know if I'm missing something.